# Does Page class adds ViewState for Controls created in CreateChildControls in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

Does Page class adds ViewState for Controls created in CreateChildControls, I mean I have a page which I add some controls to the page and all of them are Literal and EnableViewState is false, my question is are there any ViewState entry gor them in Page's ViewState?

Thank you.

Comment: I have a page with 57 KB ViewState and I don't know from where they have been generated, I just have custom controls inherited from CompositeControl in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read this and see if this is what blowing up you page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7.aspx

Looks like you can disable view state but your controls can have there own ControlState you might need to worry about.

Also if you are adding these controls into a DataGrid, The DataGrid, stores all of its contents in the view state.

Look here :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic9

Comment: Thanks so much, DataGrid stores all of its contents in the view state, how about Repeater?

Comment: I am not sure... I would have to look around, but its worth a try.